# how to efficiently work through algorithms on paper

Tags: algorithm

I am currently reading a programming text book and as I discover different algorithms used in the book I'm finding it necessary to understand how they work by working through them. Is there a standard & efficient way to work through simple algorithms on paper?

Comment: The word "efficiently" is perhaps out of place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the algorithm down on the paper. Write the corresponding graphs and variables that you use in algorithm.

Now follow algorithm step by step and note what changed with variables and graphs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Time slices. Make a table, where the column headers are variables involved, and row headers are step numbers. Fill in row zero with initial values if any, and each row represents the result of the current step on the previous row.